# Angular and Tern.js - ReferenceError in angular.js

Tags: javascript, tern

I'm trying to configure Emacs with Tern.js to use AngularJS in it.
When add angular to `.tern-project` like:

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "node": {
    },
    "angular": {
    }
  }
}
```

and type `app.|` I get ReferenceError in Angular itself printed in minibuffer:

```
/my/project/home/angular.js:26307
})(window, document);
   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/project/home/angular.js:26307:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at loadPlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tern/bin/tern:111:15)
    at startServer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tern/bin/tern:136:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tern/bin/tern:132:14)
)
```

Does anyone have some experience with this or advice?

Comment: A shot in the dark: maybe, similar to jslint it could understand `/* global: window */` comment in the file? The problem is that you must be trying to run this in a NodeJS or similar environment (outside of a browser), which doesn't define `window` and `document` variables. However, even if you will get Tern to ignore these, this means that any code that actually uses them will fail. Another option would be to search for a JavaScript library which imitates `window` and `document` API.

Comment: See if https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom will help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `window` object is [provided by the `browser` lib](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/blob/master/defs/browser.json), so you'll need something like:

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "node": {},
    "angular": {}
    }
  }
}
```